# What do I need to do about these errors / messages in output from NPM?

Tags: macos, npm, command-line-interface, macos-sierra, hyperledger-composer

I am installing the `CLI Tools` for a `local Hyperledger Composer dev environment` on a `MacBook Pro (MacOS 10.13.2)` and have deprecation / package name change messages come up in the output from `NPM`. To do the install I am following the instructions from this location:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html

My question is do I need to take action based on these messages (see below), or can I just continue? Please forgive the basic question, but am a total newb at this level of work on a Mac - am doing it for a Hyperledger course on Coursera.org.

This is the command that I run: `npm install -g composer-cli`

...and here are the first few lines of output:

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
```

then a little further down I get this:

```
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
```

### Update (2018-01-11)

Am continuing following Joe Clay's reply below and now just run this command: `npm install -g composer-playground`

...and get the following warnings at the end of the output from NPM:

```
npm WARN ngx-clipboard@8.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-clipboard@8.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-clipboard@8.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-clipboard@8.0.4 requires a peer of core-js@>=2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-window-token@0.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-window-token@0.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-window-token@0.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-window-token@0.0.2 requires a peer of core-js@>=2.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Will continue for now and see if these warnings affect the final dev env't. Am a bit disappointed with the IBM crowd for giving code like this to students :(

Thanks muchly in advance for your help!

cheers, Lawrence

Comment: Those warnings are appearing because `composer-cli` has dependencies on outdated libraries. Short of submitting a pull request to Composer's GitHub to update the libraries, there's nothing you can do about them. Shouldn't cause issues on your end, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe. I'll continue with the next install step then and keep my fingers crossed :)

Comment: dont be upset with IBM, out of date dependencies are one of the annoying things about using angular you'll have to live with. everything goes out of date fast, then is depreciated fast... #sigh 

no such thing as LTE in angular extensions, unlike other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Endorsing Joe Clay's response, you can ignore those messages as he has articulated. peerDependencies is defined in package.json (referring to the Angular messages, which Playground depends on).

Hyperledger consists of a number of members (not just IBM please note) - see more here -> https://www.hyperledger.org/members that contribute code to projects such as Hyperledger Compoer (one such incubation project)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul. In the end I decided to install the missing peerDependencies, but left the other warnings for now. The Playground installation and Composer CLI Tools seem to be working OK for now.  
  
Do you think it's worth submitting a pull request to the Composer team through Github? It would probably be better if they weren't using a build with so many outdated dependencies.

Comment: sure, you can if you wish and make suggestions / contribute code changes  too if you wish.